# How to fix that If get's ignored in while

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I want to program a crude http client to send some weather data from a to b but in an important while loop if `if(SocketServer.send)` returns false.

```
SocketServer.stringOut = "test message";
SocketServer.send = true;
while (true){
    SocketServer.stringIn = inputReader.readLine();
    if(SocketServer.send){
    System.out.println("SENDING TEXT MESSAGE");
        outputWriter.println(SocketServer.stringOut);
        SocketServer.send = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean `How to fix that If get's ignored in while`?

Comment: Did you provide an input for readline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed it. It was kind of stupid from me but i have to accept that. The problem was that the bufferedReader broke the while loop

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when you said

> if the statements were ignored in the while loop

You meant

> If `if(SocketServer.send)` returns false

```
SocketServer.stringOut = "test message";
SocketServer.send = true;
while (true){
    SocketServer.stringIn = inputReader.readLine();
    if(SocketServer.send){
        System.out.println("SENDING TEXT MESSAGE");
        outputWriter.println(SocketServer.stringOut);
        SocketServer.send = false;
    }
    else{ // If **if(SocketServer.send)** returns false
        //Send messages, i.e.
        b.send(SocketServer.stringOut);
    }
}
```

Comment: At first sorry for my bad english and the names of the variables so with "send" i meant "should the program send it". My problem lays  there that every if (/else) statement i use in while loops doesn't get executed even when the argument is true

Comment: With the else statement I added, there are only two possibilities. 



SocketServer.send = true (triggers if statement. It cannot execute the else statement in the same execution of the loop), or



SocketServer.send = false. (Triggers else statement)



It should not be possible that neither the If-Statement or the Else-Statement should function.

Comment: Both java.util.Scanner and java.util.BufferedReader wait for an input from an InputStream. (Or some other form of input, because your BufferedReader was waiting for an input.) I have just realized that Benitok has actually found your solution far before either of us posted anything here.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, then mark it as the correct answer to close the discussion.